# Checking number patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex

How can I check in Python whether a number is built in this pattern:

```
1. 57.00057  
2. 611.000000611  
3. 389.00003890000389
```

There's the number, then a certain number of zero's after the dot and then the number again. This can occur multiply times after the dot (Like in example 3).

Answer (score 4):

```
def test(number):
    return bool(re.match(r'^(\d+)\.(0+\1)+$', number))
```

Comment: Nice and compact, Daniel.